# golang RFC2822 conversion

Tags: go, timestamp, date-conversion

Is there a library or function in the included libraries that converts an RFC timestamp to Unix time (or another format that I can then format into Unix time?)

For example, I'd like to change this `Tue Sep 16 21:58:58 +0000 2014` to a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s := "Tue Sep 16 21:58:58 +0000 2014"
    const rfc2822 = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
    t, err := time.Parse(rfc2822, s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    u := t.Unix()
    fmt.Println(u)
    f := t.Format(time.UnixDate)
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

Output:

```
1410904738
Tue Sep 16 21:58:58 +0000 2014
```

References:

[Package time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/)

[RFC2822: 3.3. Date and Time Specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)

NOTE:

There is a package `time` format constant named `RubyDate`; it's a misnomer.

The Go authors were misled by Go Issue 518 which claimed that Ruby `Time.now` outputs `Tue Jan 12 02:52:59 -0800 2010`. However,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
print Time.now
print "\n"
```

Output:

```
2014-09-20 19:40:32 -0400
```

Later, the issue was revised to say that `Tue Jan 12 02:52:59 -0800 2010` was the date format used by the Twitter API. In the beginning, in the "Fail Whale" days, Twitter used Ruby-on-Rails, which may be why they assumed it was a Ruby date format.

I didn't use the `time.RubyDate` constant in my example since it's misleading. A constant named `rfc2822` provides better documentation.

References:

[Go: Issue 518: time.Parse - numeric time zones and spacing](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=518)

[Diff of format.go revision 0f80c5e80c0e](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/diff?spec=svn0f80c5e80c0e687d3064e4422b1f86508a87ec3e&name=0f80c5e80c&r=0f80c5e80c0e687d3064e4422b1f86508a87ec3e&format=side&path=/src/pkg/time/format.go)

[Twitter Search is Now 3x Faster](https://blog.twitter.com/2011/twitter-search-now-3x-faster)

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood can you expand on that? Is there a `time.RubyDate` method in the golang `time` package?

Comment: @bvpx not a method, but a time format, with the same definition as above `RubyDate = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"`

Comment: @bvpx: See my revised answer for a note about `time.RubyDate`.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood: The name `RubyDate` is a misnomer.

Comment: This doesn't appear to follow RFC 2822. According to page 13, a comma should follow the day-of-week. Also, the date should be in the format "day month year" - your example has the year at the end of the format string. I believe the correct format string should be as follows: `Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700`